# Syntax of Array and Functions in apple Dylan

Tags: arrays, function, syntax, dylan

i am new with apple dylan and I can't find in the net what is the syntax of Arrays and Dylan.I'll be glad, if you give me some examples too.
Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

It's defined in the [Dylan Reference Manual (Expressions)](http://opendylan.org/books/drm/Expressions#IX-217): `#[1, 2, 3]` for a literal vector (in Dylan, the class `<vector>` is a one-dimensional array).

The literal syntax is only valid if there are literal values inside, otherwise:

```
 let foo = 20;
 let arr = vector(foo, foo, foo);
```

or

```
 let arr = make(<vector>, size: 10, fill: 200);
```

Access for a specific element is done with the generic function `element`, which has some syntactic sugar:

```
 let 1st-element = arr[0]; // equivalent to let 1st-element = element(arr, 0)
 arr[1] := 10; //equivalent to element-setter(10, arr, 1)
```